# Mailgun response The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, cloudflare, mailgun

I have a problem sending emails (API HTTP request - .Net Core) using Mailgun from the server.

If I am using the localhost, then the emails are being sent correctly but as soon as I publish the app on the server and try to send the email I get (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)

I am not sure if it’s a server SSL issue, Mailgun issue or Cloudflare issue.

I wonder if someone faced this issue before.

I spend the last 3 days (a few hours a day) trying to fix this issue but I am not getting anywhere.

*Cname is: email.descod.net*

Thanks

Comment: To learn why SSL/TLS connections cannot be created, you need to use a tool like Wireshark and a lot of networking knowledge. Escalate this to someone in your team, or hire a consultant. Don't expect someone here can easily help.

Comment: There are too few details to debug the problem. But make sure that your production server even allows accessing arbitrary mail servers. Often access is restricted to the mail server provided by the hosting providers in order to have more control how much and what is sent and thus to prevent misuse of the hosting service for sending spam.

Answer (score 0):

this issue was fixed by publishing the SSL certificate 1 more time and restarting the server (I think the restart did the trick)